# FasfKafka library: how to commit messages in consumer manually when enable_autocommit=False?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, fastapi

I want to read messages from Kafka topic (wrapping my message processor with `consumes` decorator of `fastkafka` library).

But I want not just to auto-commit messages, but to commit them manually -- and only if the message processing was correct (when my extra function that was processing their internal data did not throw any exception).

How can it be done? How can I commit messages manually -- and only when I really want to commit them?

Comment: Did you try disable enable.auto.commit ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I set `enable_auto_commit=False` in my `@kafka_app.consumes` decorator arguments. Buy I don't know hot to commit messages manually in `fastkafka`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.... Authors of fastkafka told that is's not yet implemented: https://github.com/airtai/fastkafka/issues/467